# How do I retrain my machine learning model without merging the new data with the old data?

Tags: machine-learning

How to re-train a machine learning model without merging the old data with the new data?

1. I have one model which is performing well on some data, now in my requirement, I will be having data coming and I need to retrain my model based on the new coming data.
2. Now I have saved my first model where the I got a good accuracy but I don't want to add the new data to my old data and retrain the model with the new set of data, reason being my old data is huge so it is computationally very expensive and time taking to merge the old and new set.
3. I saved my model as a .pickle file and tried running the same model with my new set of data hoping that the new model would be able to work great with my new train data. But I noticed that the new model got retrained with the new data itself and the old memories are just gone now.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, The model learns from the new data, "its memories" won't go away. The model gets generalised for both new data and old data. Maybe before training with new data, test the model on the new data and find how good its metrics are. If it is **too good** dont train it.

Comment: @Justice_Lords No, that's not true, Catastrophical forgetting will happen. Unfortunately this is a research problem, not a programming one.

Comment: Hi Justice! Thanks for your response. Actually yes the new model is actually overwriting the old model. I tried this with my code. I even tried taking the parameters of the old model and tried fitting it with the new one. same result. So long story short it doesn't work.

Comment: I retrained some new data on the model, and the performance was downgraded. When merging the new and old data, the performance increased a bit.